# Dialogflow webhook node.js - Add handler/middleware that runs *after* intent is handled

Tags: node.js, express, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm using the Dialogflow node.js webhook component with express. Here's the boilerplate.

```
import { dialogflow } from 'actions-on-google';
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

// app init, handle intents
const app = dialogflow()
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  conv.ask('Welcome to the awesome reminder action!');
});
app.intent('Some Custom Intent', conv => {
  conv.ask('Say something');
});

// bind to express
express().use(bodyParser.json(), app).listen(5000)
```

Now, I can add a middleware to the dialogflow app (with `app.middleware(function)`) that runs *before* intents are handled. Does anyone know how to add a middleware that runs *after* intents are handled?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe these [solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24258782/node-express-4-middleware-after-routes) [solution2](https://community.apigee.com/questions/12183/usage-of-middleware-after-response-sent.html) [solution3](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3275-you-can-continue-to-process-an-express-js-request-after-the-client-response-has-been-sent.htm) may help you. Otherwise, you may try and call the after function after calling `conv.ask` or `conv.close` like

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  conv.ask('Welcome to the awesome reminder action!');
  // call after function here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Naturally I can add it at the end of the intent handling but my question is about having more than one intent. I've edited the code in my question to reflect that

Comment: Did you check the link I have put? Did it help?

Comment: I checked it but I don't know how to translate it to my use case. I think the dialogflow object handles the requests.

Comment: If you want to add something with Dialogflow after the call, it may not work. But something that you want to do like logging etc may work with express middlewares.