# Express: Get the data sent on finish

Tags: express

I would like to create and `express.use` a middleware that gets the data sent from all endpoints and use it for caching. But I am unable to get that data with `res.on('finish', cb)`. Is there even such a thing ?

Thank you

Comment: does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29442079/8844451

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node Express 4 middleware after routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24258782/node-express-4-middleware-after-routes)

Comment: No, I am trying to get the data send from `res.send(data);` in the middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add middleware and override existing **res.send** function with your custom function like below

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const { send } = res;
  res.send = (data) => {
    // Store in cache
    return send(data);
  };
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I will close my question since I found a way myself :

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const send = res.send;

  res.send = (data) => {
    res.send = send; // this line is important not to have an infinite loop

    // do something with `data`

    return res.send(data);
  };

  next();
});
```